# how to to convert for to foreach

Tags: for-loop, foreach

jslint tell Unexpected 'for'.
so i think that i must convert for with foreach
but how?
if someone can help
thanks

```
// Grab the original element
var original    = document.getElementsByTagName("noscript")[0];
// Create a replacement tag of the desired type
var replacement = document.createElement("span");
var i;
// Grab all of the original's attributes, and pass them to the replacement
for(i = 0, l = original.attributes.length; i < l; ++i){
    var nodeName  = original.attributes.item(i).nodeName;
    var nodeValue = original.attributes.item(i).nodeValue;

    replacement.setAttribute(nodeName, nodeValue);
}

// Persist contents
replacement.innerHTML = original.innerHTML;

// Switch!
original.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, original);
```

Comment: did the answer below work for you ?

Comment: If your question is about specific code, make sure you include a tag for the language to help classify/identify the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma after `i = 0,` <========
it should be semicolon.
Another issue is declaring `l = original.attributes.length`  you don't need the variable `l`
just use it as `for(i = 0; i < original.attributes.length; ++i){`

if you still wanna use a forEach you can do it as:

```
original.attributes.forEach(element => {
    var nodeName  = element.nodeName;
    var nodeValue = element.nodeValue;

    replacement.setAttribute(nodeName, nodeValue);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks for your answer, i got Uncaught TypeError: original.attributes.forEach is not a function

```
function Switch() {

var original    = document.getElementsByTagName("noscript")[0];
var replacement = document.createElement("span");

original.attributes.forEach(element => {
    var nodeName  = element.nodeName;
    var nodeValue = element.nodeValue;

    replacement.setAttribute(nodeName, nodeValue);
});

// Persist contents
replacement.innerHTML = original.innerHTML;

// Switch!
original.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, original);

}
```